# How GetProcessElevation implemented and Why it need TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE*

Tags: c++, c, windows, security, winapi

I wanted to check the privilege that my executable is given by the user, so I find out the following function. The function works fine but I couldn't realize why GetProcessElevation implemented in this way and why it calls CreateWellKnownSid and gets a pointer to TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE as an argument. Someone could explain it line by line?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE g_tet_ElevationType = TokenElevationTypeDefault;
BOOL                 g_b_IsAdmin = FALSE;

BOOL GetProcessElevation(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE* arg_elevation_type, BOOL* arg_is_admin) {
    HANDLE h_Token = NULL;
    DWORD dw_Size;

    // Get current process token
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &h_Token))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    BOOL b_Result = FALSE;

    // Retrieve elevation type information
    if (GetTokenInformation(h_Token, TokenElevationType, arg_elevation_type, sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE), &dw_Size)) {

        // Create the SID corresponding to the Administrators group
        BYTE l_bt_AdminSID[SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE];
        dw_Size = sizeof(l_bt_AdminSID);
        CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, &l_bt_AdminSID, &dw_Size);

        if (*arg_elevation_type == TokenElevationTypeLimited) {

            // Get handle to linked token (will have one if we are lua)
            HANDLE hUnfilteredToken = NULL;
            GetTokenInformation(h_Token, TokenLinkedToken, (VOID*)&hUnfilteredToken, sizeof(HANDLE), &dw_Size);

            // Check if this original token contains admin SID
            if (CheckTokenMembership(hUnfilteredToken, &l_bt_AdminSID, arg_is_admin)) {
                b_Result = TRUE;
            }

            // Don't forget to close the unfiltered token
            CloseHandle(hUnfilteredToken);
        }
        else {
            *arg_is_admin = IsUserAnAdmin();
            b_Result = TRUE;
        }
    }

    // Don't forget to close the process token
    CloseHandle(h_Token);
    return b_Result;
}


// returns 0 if an Admin and/or elevated
// returns 1 if a filtered user token (Admin but UAC'd)
// returns 2 if a regular user
// returns 5 if none of the standard elevation types match
// returns 10 if GetProcessElevation failed
int GetUserTokenStatus()
{
    int dw_UserTokenStatus = 10;
    if (GetProcessElevation(&g_tet_ElevationType, &g_b_IsAdmin)) {
        switch (g_tet_ElevationType) {
        // Default user or UAC is disabled
        case TokenElevationTypeDefault:
            if (IsUserAnAdmin()) {
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 0;
            }
            else {
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 2;
            }
            break;

        // Process has been successfully elevated
        case TokenElevationTypeFull:
            if (IsUserAnAdmin()) {
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 0;
            }
            else {
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 0;
            }
            break;

        // Process is running with limited privileges
        case TokenElevationTypeLimited:
            if (IsUserAnAdmin()) {
                // Not sure what capabilities a filtered Admin has
                // So, for now, I'll treat that as non-Admin
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 3;
            }
            else {
                dw_UserTokenStatus = 1;
            }
            break;

        default:
            dw_UserTokenStatus = 5;
        }
    }

    return dw_UserTokenStatus;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (GetUserTokenStatus() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "I am Administrator." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "I am Standard User." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you don't get exactly about the function argument; if you look on the MSDN at [GetTokenInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) you clearly see that the type of the 3rd arg depends on the class of the 2nd. In the case of `TokenElevationType` being the 2nd arg, the 3rd one must be a pointer to a `TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE` as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class).

Comment: `GetProcessElevation` is inconsistent. `IsUserAnAdmin` calls `CheckTokenMemberShip` with `TokenHandle` as `NULL`, which will use the thread token when impersonating. If it's always supposed to check the process user, then all cases should call `CheckTokenMemberShip` directly using the process token, or the linked token in the limited case (i.e. close the limited token and set `h_Token` to the linked token). If it's supposed to check the effective user, then it should first try `OpenThreadToken` and fall back on `OpenProcessToken`.